# What's the advantages of angular's dependency injection when I can use import/export in es6

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I just moved into a company using AngularJS (1.x) stack.
Coming from a es6(babel)+webpack+redux+react background, I was wondering what are the benefits of using AngularJS dependency injection when I can simply import/export files.
Frankly, import/export gives me locations of files to look for, but AngularJS dependency injection doesn't seem to have that in mind.
(Also, angularJS services, factories, etc. seem to be replaceable with ES6 classes, export/imports, etc.)

Are there any noticeable benefits on using AngularJS dependency injection and angularjs-specific dependencies (such as $http, etc.) rather than moving to alternatives? (such as jquery's ajax, etc.)

thank you : )

Comment: I'm not sure what benefits are one over the other. But if your new company works with angularjs 1.x. If the app is big it will take you a lot of time changing things everywhere. I'm not sure they would want that. Also other developers are not used to es6 maybe you should consider that also.

Comment: Bear in mind that Angular was written before ES6 was a real thing, also before babel, webpack and react.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I guess that explains a lot... also, are there anything more 'special' to angular services/factories/etc. compared to what es6 classes can do?

Comment: You are mixing together dependency injection and module loading, and on top on that you add a question about using alternatives to angular providers.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin  I'm thinking about persuading the team to move to es6-wonderland, but I'm also wondering whether there would be some hidden pitfalls (e.g. hidden angularJS magic on services/etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Module loading and Dependency Injection are two different ideas.

Module loading is about locating your source.  DI is about automatically wiring your objects together.

Angular allows you to specify a provider which gives you the ability to configure your code before injection.  I recommend you take a look at this link.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

The other value that angular's DI framework has is making it easier to write tests as you can easily replace your services.

As for moving away from Angular specific services, I would recommend against that as these services are not hooked into your scope, so you may have to call $scope.apply() everywhere.

All that said, you could argue that DI is less useful in a language like Javascript as it is not class driven such as Java and C#.

Comment: In that case, how about making a hybrid of module-loading and dependency injection?
e.g.) 

var test = getInjectableRequire('./path/to/some/file.js');

(and in the test file):
setInjectableRequire('./path/to/some/file.js', <alternative dependency> ) ?

Comment: I have never used it, but I think OC lazy load does something like this. https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/dependency-injection